# Solve $f(x)+f'(x)=x$.

Tags: calculus

If $f'(x) + f(x) = x,\;$ find $f(4)$.

Could someone help me to solve this problem ?

The answer is 3 but I don't know why.
*with no use of integration or exponential functions* and
*the function is polynomial*

Comment: do have any other condition?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner no this is the exact question from my textbook

Comment: but the solution of your equation containes a constant.

Comment: we get$$f(x)=-1+x+Ce^{-x}$$

Comment: You say "the answer is $3$" but it does not even seem that the answer to your (actually not asked) question is a number.

Comment: it is just corrected

Comment: $f(4)=-1+4+Ce^{-4}$

Comment: If that is the question as given, there is no way to compute $f(4)$.

Comment: Ok, guys. Let's try to find a different solution without using $e$ by assuming $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: You know that $f$ is a polynomial. So, set $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^Na_nx^n$, derive, set up your equation and compare coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

hint: multiplying both side by $e^x$ we have

$$f'(x) + f(x) = x\Longleftrightarrow  ( f(x)e^x)'= xe^x
\Longleftrightarrow  f(x)e^x= xe^x -e^x +c.
$$ 
can you continue from here ?

Comment: There is a constant of integration that should render $f(x)$ uncertain up to a constant time $e^{-x}$.

Comment: ok now there is the next term . I left the rest to the OP

Comment: @robjohn this question should not contain integration as it was an exercise on implicit and parametric differentiation

Comment: @user8700093: however the equation is solved, there is a family of solutions and each one satisfies the differential equation and each one differs from the others by a constant times $e^{-x}$.

Comment: Regardless of any other solution that uses the exponential function or integration , this question should not be solved like that as it's an exercise on implicit and parametric differentiation before the chapters of e and integration

Comment: @user8700093: Ah, so there is the [context that should have been included in the question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). This is the reason that context is required for good questions. You don't know how to integrate and you don't know anything about exponential functions. The question then remains: how can you possibly solve this equation without simply guessing (in this case, guessing that it is a polynomial will give *one solution*).

Comment: Yes i should have done that , fool me , anyways i said that this exercise was given to me before i studied integration and exponential functions , i now studied it but i'am looking for the simpler and shorter answer .. Edited it thanks

Answer (score 1):

if $f'(x) + f(x) = x$ then $f'(x)e^x + f(x)e^x = xe^x$ now remember derivative by parts? $(f(x)g(x))'=f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)$. if $g(x)=e^x$ then you have $(f(x)e^x)'=f'(x)e^x+\left[e^x\right]'f(x)$ and because $\left[e^x\right]'=e^x$ you have $(f(x)e^x)'=f'(x)e^x+e^xf(x)$ so you left with:$$f'(x) + f(x) = x\implies f'(x)e^x + f(x)e^x = xe^x\implies(f(x)e^x)'=xe^x\\\implies f(x)e^x=\int xe^x\ dx=xe^x -e^x +c$$

Edit

If you know it is polynomial then:

We can assume that $f(x)$ is first degree and we get
$$f(x) + f'(x)= x\\(ax+b)+(a)=x\\(ax)+(b+a)=x\\\begin{cases}a=1\\b+a=0\implies b+1=0\implies b=-1\end{cases}$$
And you finally get $f(x)=x-1$ just put $4$ instead of $x$ and you'll get $3$

Comment: That is the exact same answer as that of Guy Fsone.

Comment: @amsmath i just noticed, it took me time to write the explanation...

Comment: Thanks so much Mr. Holo but i took this exercise before studying the exponential functions and integration so i think there must be an another solution without them and it should be way shorter

Comment: @user8700093 please look at the edit

Comment: Thanks so much !!

Answer (score 0):

The only way f is a polynomial is if it is of 1st degree because $ deg( f'(x)+f(x))=deg(x)=1$. Since $degf'(x)<degf(x)$ we obtain that $degf(x)=1$ so you can set $ f(x)=ax+b$ so we get that $ f'(x)=a $. Plug those in and:
$ f'(x)+f(x)=x=> ax+(a+b)=x $